# Where to attach extra wires in pull-cord fixture

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, safety

We have a light fixture box in our stairwell that I’m trying to put a new light on. When our 60+ yo house was wired 25 years ago, the electrician took out the wall switch it was connected to and replaced the light with one with a pull chain. I can’t remember why he did it. I now want to replace the fixture with a new one, also a pull-chain light. Both the white and the black wires are hot, because there’s no wall switch—they’re just wired to be always on. I take it I can turn off the breaker, wire the fixture to the box, white-to-white/black-to-black, turn the breaker back on and the house shouldn’t burn down. Right?

And follow-up: In addition to the black, white, and ground wires, the pull-cord fixture has two more black wires coming out of the pull-cord switch itself. Where should these be connected?

After edit:

[image: pull-chain wires]

[image: wall box wires]

Comment: Pictures will help, but usually connect the same as before.  The pull chain should be connected to one black from the ceiling/wall and to black wire/brass screw of the fixture.

Comment: Sorry. Image now attached to original post. In between time, I tried connecting one pull-switch wire each with the + and - connections. When I turned the breaker back on, there was no current at all. Turned breaker back off, disconnected everything, turned breaker back on, and there was a hot wire again, though this time only the black one (as it should have been), not both black & white (as it had been before). #whateversmostcomplicated

Answer (score 1):

The black socket wire and one of the switch wires need to be spliced.  It seems the manufacturer was too cheap and lazy to ship this product fully assembled.

The remaining switch wire needs to be spliced to the line hot, hopefully also black.

Yes, you should be good with splicing the two white wires.

Remember the ground wire (green stripe) must be connected too.  This is a code requirement for luminaires with metal parts unless GFCI protected.